# How to find the probability that two Normally Distributed events occur within a certain range of each other?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm going to formulate a particular problem that will hopefully allow my original question to be answered:

Suppose two people, Bob and Jim are dueling each other, take ten paces in either direction so that they are 6m from each other. The time it takes for both Bob and Jim to shoot after walking 6m is normally distributed with a mean of 200ms and standard deviation of 25ms, and if we say the bullet travels at 600 m/s , this means the bullet will take 10ms to reach the other target.

If we assume that both Bob and Jim never miss, what is the probability that both Bob and Jim are both dead after the duel.

I believe this is the same as saying, what is the probability that two normally distributed events with mean 200 and s.d. 25 have values less than 10 from each other i.e. $p\left(\left|X-Y\right|<10\right)$ where $X$ may represent one normal distribution and $Y$ another identical one.

Unfortunately whilst I do have a basic understanding of probability distributions, I have few ideas about how to approach this problem; any explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: make a 2dimensional distribution X in one and Y in the other, then figure out the area of integration for density functions that fulfill $|X-Y|<10$ and then integrate.

Comment: What do you know about the probability distribution of $Z=X-Y$?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is fine.

You should use kimchi lover's hint:

> If $X_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $X_2 \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ are independent, then $X_1+X_2 \sim N(\mu_1,\mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)$.

Apply this to $X \sim N(200, 25^2)$ and $(-Y) \sim N(-200, 25^2)$ to find the distribution of $X-Y$. Then $P(|X-Y|<10)$ can be readily computed using a table.